# moralis connect walletconnect TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importKey')

Tags: walletconnect, moralis

guy i use moralis plugin connect wallet.

but found error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importKey').

i don't know why. i follow example in document.

this my code.

```
import Moralis from 'moralis';
         async loginWalletConnect() {
            
            const account = await Moralis.authenticate({provider: 'walletconnect', chainId: 56});
            const userWeb3 = await Moralis.enableWeb3({provider: 'walletconnect', chainId: 56});
            
        },
```

When click login walletconnect it genarate qr code, but in console show error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importKey').
and can't connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my answer it problem from url address.
in my local set virtual host blockee.test, so i try many times i found the answer at http://localhost

**My answer is user http://localhost or localhost:[port] when test *walletconnect* or *coinbase***